# Error : Runtime compiler is not loaded : On production build in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, lazy-loading, angular-aot

I have been working on angular 7 project and implemented lazy loading of a module as followed in app.route:

```
  { path: 'privacy-statement',  loadChildren: () => import('./privacy-statement/privacy-statement.module').then(m => m.PrivacyStatementModule) }
```

It's working fine on normal serve but when I serve the app with --prod and try to access 'privacy-statement', It throws the following error

> Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
>       at n.Ht (main.fd01867a26977f516ab1.js:1)
>       at t.project (main.fd01867a26977f516ab1.js:1)
>       at t._tryNext (main.fd01867a26977f516ab1.js:1)
>       at t._next (main.fd01867a26977f516ab1.js:1)
>       at t.next (main.fd01867a26977f516ab1.js:1)
>       at main.fd01867a26977f516ab1.js:1
>       at e.invoke (polyfills.a7106ca102d40b2f087a.js:1)
>       at Object.onInvoke (main.fd01867a26977f516ab1.js:1)
>       at e.invoke (polyfills.a7106ca102d40b2f087a.js:1)
>       at t.run (polyfills.a7106ca102d40b2f087a.js:1)
>       at P (polyfills.a7106ca102d40b2f087a.js:1)
>       at P (polyfills.a7106ca102d40b2f087a.js:1)
>       at polyfills.a7106ca102d40b2f087a.js:1
>       at e.invokeTask (polyfills.a7106ca102d40b2f087a.js:1)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (main.fd01867a26977f516ab1.js:1)
>       at e.invokeTask (polyfills.a7106ca102d40b2f087a.js:1)
>       at t.runTask (polyfills.a7106ca102d40b2f087a.js:1)
>       at g (polyfills.a7106ca102d40b2f087a.js:1)

I have searched for a solution and found that If I disable AOT (set it to false), It does work.
But It increases the serve-time significantly so Is there any other solution that doesn't affect load time?

Answer (score 0):

To use the import like you did is only possible in AOT if you have [`ivy`](https://angular.io/guide/ivy) enabled. You can do this by adding an option in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": true
}
```

If you do not want to use ivy yet, because it might not be working for your app yet, you have to use the old way of lazy loading:

```
{ 
  path: 'privacy-statement', 
  loadChildren: 'path/from/src/privacy-statement/privacy-statement.module#PrivacyStatementModule'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy-loading with `import()` syntax is available from Angular 8, so either upgrade to 8 or use old syntax with string.

```
loadChildren: './path/privacy-statement.module#PrivacyStatementModule'
```